# JPlugin properties not available in child of child class

Tags: plugins, joomla, php-7

I'm writing a Joomla user plugin (Joomla 3.8 and PHP 7.0) and I'm having some trouble with inheritance. A child class can access the properties and methods of a parent using:

```
$this->[propertyormethod]
```

but ....

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

class PlgUserMyPluginParent extends JPlugin
{

    public function onUserAfterLogin($options = array())
    {
        $MyPluginChildObj = new MyPluginChild;

    }
}

class MyPluginChild extends PlgUserMyPluginParent
{   

    public function __construct()
    {
        var_dump($this->params);
        die;    
    }
}
```

In the above, the method `onUserAfterLogin()` fires as expected when a user completes login.

Because `$params` is set by JPlugin and PlgUserMyPluginParent extends JPlugin, I can access `$params` (and other JPlugin properties) inside methods of the PlgUserMyPluginParent class thus:

```
$this->params
```

So far so good. But when I extend PlgUserMyPluginParent with MyPluginChild, `$this->params` is null, as are any properties I set directly in PlgUserMyPluginParent and try to access from MyPluginChild.

For example, if I declare in PlgUserMyPluginParent:

```
public $myParentClassProperty = "somevalue";
```

then try to access it from MyPluginChild using `$this->myParentClassProperty`, it returns `null`.

Can someone please shed some light on what is going on here?

Comment: Just a correction on this:  public MyParentClassProperty = "somevalue"; should be public $MyParentClassProperty = "somevalue"; and it is in fact accessible from MyPluginChild using $this->MyParentClassProperty. But $this->params is not.

Answer (score 0):

You prohibited the initialisation of the plugin with your constructor.
If you use a constructor in a childclass, you should *always* call the parent's constructor explicitly.

```
class MyPluginChild extends PlgUserMyPluginParent
{   
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param   object $subject  The object to observe
     * @param   array  $config   An optional associative array of configuration settings.
     *                           Recognized key values include 'name', 'group', 'params', 'language'
     *                           (this list is not meant to be comprehensive).
     */
    public function __construct($subject, $config = [])
    {
        parent::construct($subject, $config);

        var_dump($this->params);
        die;    
    }
}
```

Then the constructor of JPlugin has a chance to populate `$params`.

Comment: Thanks nibra.  At the moment PlgUserMyPluginParent has no constructor so I get  "Call to undefined method PlgUserMyPluginParent::construct()" when I run that code.  And if I put a constructor in PlgUserMyPluginParent  the onUserAfterLogin method doesn't fire.

Comment: Your `PlgUserMyPluginParent` extends from `JPlugin`, which *has* a constructor. Pleas double check.

Comment: I've done some digging.  The parent class is CMSPlugin which is an abstract class and it does contain a constructor. As I understand it, when PlgUserMyPluginParent is instantiated it inherits the constructor which sets $params.

If I declare a property in PlgUserMyPluginParent (or in CMSPlugin) and assign it a value at the time of declaration it is available in MyPluginChild.  But if I set the property in PlgUserMyPluginParent it is not available in MyPluginChild.

Tell you the truth I no longer need this for my project, it just bugs me!